# Can't disable root ssh login

Tags: raspbian, ssh, login, root

I use SSH to communicate with my Raspberry Pi (server) from my laptop (Putty client).
I would like to disable root SSH login.
I change the value of "PermitRootLogin" to no in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
I restart ssh service via the cmd "sudo service ssh restart"

But, on Putty, I can always login with root password.

How can I disable root ssh login ?

Thx !

Comment: This is strange-the Pi doesn't have a root password

Comment: Does this persists after a system restart? Are you sure you didn't make a typo or edited the wrong file? Does "I can always login with root password" means you can login as root?

Answer (score 1):

You can allow or deny specific users in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by setting

```
# whitelist
AllowUsers pierrot arlecchino

# blacklist
DenyUsers innamorati pantalone
```

and then run `sudo systemctl restart ssh`. **Be advised: Before you deny users, especially the default user "pi", make sure you can login by SSH with the allowed user, else you risk to lock out yourself!**